# Выгрузка в файл http запроса к 1С - PowerShell

Tags: json, http, powershell

По этому http-запросу

```
http://%IP%/ERP_demo/hs/g...r/pass/Выбрать Код, Ссылка Из Справочник.Валюты
```

в браузере появляется окно авторизации.
После ввода логин&&пароль происходит выгрузка по запросу.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как этот запрос вместе с учетными данными выполнять с PowerShell и результат сразу записывать в JSON файл?

```
$username = 'User'
$password = 'Password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

$ИБ1 = 'http://%IP%/ERP_demo/hs/getting/user/pass/'
$ИБ2
$Запросы =
'Выбрать Код, Ссылка Из Справочник.Валюты'

foreach ($з in $Запросы)
{
    $Запрос = $ИБ1 + $з + $ИБ2
    $file = $Запрос
    $file = $file + '.json'
    $a = Invoke-RestMethod $Запрос -Credential $cred -OutFile $file
}
```

Проблема в том что сам запрос не выполняется, возникает ошибка 401.

Основу запроса позаимствовал со скрипта по выгрузке oData с 1С
Наверное, значение переменной `$cred` невозможно использовать для http

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]